# Is there an $n\ge1$ such that every prime $p\equiv1\pmod{9}$ is representable in the form $x^2+ny^2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Is there an integer $n\ge1$ such that every prime $p\equiv1\pmod{9}$ is representable in the form $x^2+ny^2$?

Comment: Set $n$ equal to $p-1$ and set $x$ and $y$ equal to $1$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I imagine, Jason, that OP doesn't want $n$ to depend on $p$. Perhaps OP could edit the question, to clarify this point?

Comment: @JasonStarr, Thanks for your comment, I am trying to find a representation of $p$ in the form $x^2+ny^2$ with $(x,y)=1$.

Comment: But $x=y=1$ satisfies $(x,y)=1$. You'll have to do better than that!

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Exactly, I would like to find an integer  $n$ which doesn't depend on $p$.

Comment: Then please edit your question to say so.

Comment: So presumably you also want to specify that $n$ should be positive, as otherwise $n=-1$ obviously works. Once that is done my guess would be that there is no such $n$.

Comment: Have you read David Cox's book *Primes of the form $X^2+nY^2$"?

Comment: Prof @JoeSilverman, I don't have access to this book.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, Yes I would like, that $n$ be different from $-1$

Comment: Is this a homework problem or take-home exam question?  What is the motivation for asking about it here? There is such an $n$ that works, and this is a standard exercise in the initial parts of algebraic number theory. As a hint, there is an $n$ which even works for all $p\equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

Comment: @nfdc23, It is not a homework problem or take-home exam question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, $n=3$ works, and no other integer works. The "no other" part follows easily by inspecting $p=19$ and $p=37$. The "works" part was conjectured by Fermat in 1654 and proved by Euler in 1772. In modern terminology, the proof is quite simple, and it goes as follows (I give an outline):

A prime $p\nmid 2n$ is represented by a primitive form of discriminant $-4n$ if and only if $(-n/p)=1$ (see Corollary 2.6 in Cox: Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$). In particular, if $x^2+ny^2$ is the only primitive form of discriminant $-4n$ up to equivalence, then a prime $p\nmid 2n$ is represented by it if and only if $(-n/p)=1$. This is certainly the case for $n=3$, and then also $(-n/p)=(p/3)$ by quadratic reciprocity. So we get that a prime $p>3$ is represented by $x^2+3y^2$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.